# Cannot read property 'length' of null when it has been initialized

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `.length` in javascript but run into `Cannot read property 'length' of null` when the `str` is not `null` (`console.log` works).

The error is in line 11.

```
import { valKey } from "./valKey"
   function promptKey(){
        let key = window.prompt("Enter a keyword.\nOnly letters and numbers:");
        return key;
    }
   console.log(promptKey());
    let isKeyValid = false;

    while (isKeyValid == false){        
        var key = promptKey();
        var keyLen = key.length; // error here
        isKeyValid = valKey(key,keyLen);  
    }
```

Comment: `prompt` returns `null` if you hit the cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` returns `null` when you click cancel on the dialog. I suggest doing something like:

```
var keyLen = (key || '').length;
```

which gives you 0 if you cancel.

Comment: Thanks this was driving me crazy.